# Axis2 implementing client side

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I need to create connection to web service with axis2. I would like to know how can I convert recieved xmls to Java objects. Is there any good tutorials to learn how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axis2 is pretty well documented. Make sure to check [the axis2 user guide](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_0/userguide3.html).
On the other hand be aware of that using web services and axis2 is not a piece
of cake sort of think, so read the docs exhausitvly. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Either the XML is part of the SOAP request. In that case, Axis2 will convert it to Java for you.

If XML is part of a "data blob", then you need to do this yourself. There are several options:

1. You can have a look at the generators which Axis2 uses. [Try the docs](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1%5F0/userguide3.html).
2. Use an XML OO mapper like [Castor](http://www.castor.org/xml-mapping.html).
3. You can write your own mapper (not really recommended).
4. If you can influence the sender side, you can try to create XML that follows the rules for [XMLEncoder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html). That would allow you to use the standard Java Serialization API to build objects.

Answer (score 1):

use axis wsdl2java tool and put generated classes to your source files. Then first create a service stub with YourServiceStub(Service_Adress) and use that instance to invoke necessary methods.

for wsdl2java i commonly use:

wsdl2java -uri wsdlLocation -ss -sd -uw -g -o outputLocation